# Using sed to write xml tag in Rakefile

Tags: ruby, xml, macos, sed, rakefile

I have trying to pre-process a xml-like file by using `Rakefile`, what I am trying to do is adding a group of xml tags.

The following `sed` is the short version of what I have done

```
sed -ig '/TARGET_STRING/{N;G;s/$/<key>KEY_NAME<\/key>/g;}' whateverfile.xml
```

and this piece of code is worked beautifully and successes while using terminal.

And I put them into the `Rakefile` I made, like this:

```
desc 'setup pods archs'
task :setup_podsarchs => :setup_submodules do
    puts 'Altering xml...'.cyan
    `sed -ig '/TARGET_STRING/{N;G;s/$/<key>KEY_NAME<\/key>/g;}' whateverfile.xml`
end
```

After executing `rake`, it prompt an error and terminate the task

```
sed: 1: "/TARGET_STRING/{N;G;s/$/ ...": bad flag in substitute command: 'k'
```

I had searching around for a long time, cannot find any information about escaping the `<` and `>` characters in `Ruby`.

---

My platform

- OS: Mac OS X 10.9
- Ruby: 2.0.0p247
- rake: 0.9.6
- sed: 7

---

**Update**

Hi, thank you guys for the extremely fast reply.

and @the Tin Man,
for the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366847/using-sed-to-write-xml-tag-in-rakefile#comment30407041_20366847),

What I am trying to do is pre-process the Xcode project file (.pbxproj), which is structured as a xml,

For simplicity, I just show the example of xml structure here:

```
<dict>
    <key>Key_ONE</key>
    <string>1</string>
</dict>
```

What I am trying to do is finding the `KEY_ONE` and adding another key after that:

```
<dict>
    <key>Key_ONE</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>Key_TWO</key>
    <string>2</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: If you're processing XML, why are you trying to use a regular expression? Instead use a parser, such as [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org), which is the most-used one for Ruby. Show us a reasonable sample of your XML, and what you expect it the result to look like and we can help you do it the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expressions for anything beyond the most trivial and controlled parsing leads to madness. Use [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org), an excellent Ruby XML/HTML parser. For instance:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = <<EOT
<xml>
  <foo>foo</foo>
  <bar>bar</bar>
</xml>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)

doc.at('foo').content = 'bar'
doc.at('bar')['class'] = 'cyan'

puts doc.to_xml
```

Which outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
  <foo>bar</foo>
  <bar class="cyan">bar</bar>
</xml>
```

Notice the content inside the `<foo>` tag changed, along with `<bar>` gaining an attribute.

What's important about using a parser is that the content can change, tag parameters can change, their order can move around inside the tag, tags can be split across multiple lines, and a parser will not care, whereas a regular expression will spout flames and stop working.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, I'll take a look, and take a shot.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, it's great to use other's wheel :)

Answer (score 0):

parser is better solution.

for sed point  of view try with

```
`sed -ig '/TARGET_STRING/{
    N
    s/$/\
<key>KEY_NAME<\/key>/
    }' whateverfile.xml`
```

G is normaly not needed because nothing is loaded into
g is also not needed, there is onle 1 replacement possible

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :). is there a `;` missed after `N`? it shown `sed: 1: "/TARGET_STRING/{ N s/$/  ...": extra characters at the end of N command`

Comment: error interface keyboard/chair, forget to set the script part of the answer in "code" mode. You are right on a OneLine but in this case there is no missing ; because this is a "\n" (corrected passing in code mode display). Sorry